# Lucene RangeQuery doesn't filter appropriately

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I'm using `RangeQuery` to get all the documents which have amount between say 0 to 2.
When i execute the query, Lucene gives me documents which have amount greater than 2 also. What am I missing here?

Here is my code:

```
Term lowerTerm = new Term("amount", minAmount);
Term upperTerm = new Term("amount", maxAmount);

RangeQuery amountQuery = new RangeQuery(lowerTerm, upperTerm, true);

finalQuery.Add(amountQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

and here is what goes into my index:

```
doc.Add(new Field("amount", amount.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED, Field.TermVector.YES));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Like @basZero said in his comment, starting with Lucene 2.9, you can add [numeric fields](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/document/NumericField.html) to your documents. Just remember to use [NumericRangeQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/NumericRangeQuery.html) instead of RangeQuery when you search.

#### Original answer

Lucene treats numbers as words, so their order is alphabetic:

```
0
1
12
123
2
22
```

That means that for Lucene, 12 is between 0 and 2. If you want to do a proper numerical range, you need to index the numbers zero-padded, then do a range search of [0000 TO 0002]. (The amount of padding you need depends on the expected range of values).

If you have negative numbers, just add another zero for non-negative numbers. (EDIT: **WRONG WRONG WRONG**. See update)

If your numbers include a fraction part, leave it as is, and zero-pad the integer part only.

Example:

```
-00002.12
-00001
```

```
000000
000001
000003.1415
000022
```

**UPDATE**: Negative numbers are a bit tricky, since -1 comes before -2 alphabetically. [This article](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/SearchNumericalFields) gives a complete explanation about dealing with negative numbers and numbers in general in Lucene. Basically, you have to "encode" numbers into something that makes the order of the items make sense.

Comment: could you please let me know how do i use rangequery for decimal numbers?thanks!

Comment: For decimals (I assume you mean decimals with a fractional component) you need to scale them up, eg. by multiplying by a million, and removing any remainder: 1.2 -> 1200000.  The amount you multiply by depends on how many decimal places you need to be accurate to.

Comment: ...and of course you still need to zero-pad them, as itsadok says.  I should have said 1.2 -> 0001200000

Comment: No need to scale up. Alphabetically, 1.234 comes before 1.3.

Comment: Hi isadok,
As you already know lat/long can be decimal/negative numbers.
is below the correct way of indexing a city's lat and long positions in Lucene?

string paddedLatitude = PadNumber(latitude);
string paddedLongitude = PadNumber(longitude);

doc.Add(new Field("latitude", paddedLatitude, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED));

doc.Add(new Field("longitude", paddedLongitude, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED));

example:
paddedLongitude-->"0041.811846"
paddedLongitude-->"-087.820628"

Thanks.

Comment: That looks about OK. Please post this as a question, and I promise to answer.

Comment: Use Lucene 2.9.x and you can add numbers to the index.

Answer (score 0):

I created a PHP function that convert numerics to lucene/solr range searchables.

`0.5` is converted to `10000000000.5`
`-0.5` is converted to `09999999999.5`

```
function luceneNumeric($numeric)
{
    $negative = $numeric < 0;
    $numeric = $negative ? 10000000000 + $numeric : $numeric;

    $parts = explode('.', str_replace(',', '.', $numeric));

    $lucene = $negative ? 0 : 1;
    $lucene .= str_pad($parts[0], 10, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $lucene .= isset($parts[1]) ? '.' . $parts[1] : '';

    return $lucene;
}
```

It seems to work, hope this helps someone!